# Power Pages | PWA Builder Shows "No Manifest" | Should link to Web Files

Tags: html, json, progressive-web-apps, manifest

No matter how I try to link the manifest when I navigate to the PWA builder to turn my website into a PWA and generate installation files I get this error [image]

This is an issue as I have done this before but never with Power Pages. I cannot get any manifest file to be recognized by the browser for my site and this is becoming quite irritating as it should link to the web-files folder.

I attempted to link in these ways

`<link rel="manifest" href="/PWAManifest.json"/>`
`<link rel="manifest" href="/web-files/PWAManifest.json"/>`

And also tried creating a new manifest file in my home folder to reference several times, and it would not allow me to save the file to be used as a manifest. As shown here

[image]

I have tried renaming the file as well which isn't allowed for web-files that are pre configured so I am at a loss now. I am actually starting to believe this is an issue with either Power Pages or MS Edge as Edge doesn't show the resource "PAWManifest.json" or the "web-files" folder that should be linked to every page.

Here is where the default manifest that "should be recognized" is located in the visual studio project folder

[image]